# Can I have an ::after selected inside a label with an input?

Tags: html, css

I'm simulating a click effect with CSS only with labels and inputs but don't know how I can have the same effect in my `::after` pseudo-element without setting the `input` outside the `label`. I tried using flexbox `order` but it's not working.

If you run the example below you will see that the number with a yellow background is missing. Check it clicking. How can I fix this issue? Is it possible?

```css
body {
  counter-reset: step;
}

label {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

label::after {
  counter-increment: step;
  content: counter(step);
  margin-right: 10px;
}

span {
  order: 2
}

label input:checked ~ * {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="step" checked><span>Hello</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Kiss</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Bye</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the counter inside the span instead:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: step;
}

label {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  counter-increment: step;
}
label span::before  {
  content: counter(step);
  margin-right: 10px;
} 


label input:checked ~ * {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="step" checked><span>Hello</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Kiss</span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="step"><span>Bye</span></label>
```

Comment: Awesome @Temani Afif with the `counter-increment: step` in the `label` but then it's not possible anymore to change between flex direction `flex-direction: column;`. Should I make another question for this?

Comment: @JohnnyJohnny simply make the span `inline-flex` or `flex` and change the direction inside

Comment: Your are a genius, simple and easy solution, thank you so much @Termani Afif!